# Binance api python как автоматически размещать ордера на продажу лесенкой в паре с биткоином?

Tags: python, decimal

Я торгую в паре с биткоином и хочу через binance api python реализовать продажу токенов по лесенкой:
Цена покупки 0,00002750

- Цель 1 (+10%) - 3025
- Цель 2 (+20%) - 3300
- Цель 3 (+30%) - 3575
- Цель 4 (+40%) - 3850

Как конвертировать цели для продажи в такой формат 0,00003025 и тд. для размещения ордера?

```py
# получаю цену монеты 
b = prices
# делаю из 2.75e-06 это 2750 а точнее 275
c = re.sub(r"(?m)e.+$", "", str(b))
price_round = c.replace('.', '')

# и получаю такие цели 302 330 358 385
numer = str(round(int(price_round) * 10 / 100 + int(price_round)))
numer_2 = str(round(int(price_round) * 20 / 100 + int(price_round)))
numer_3 = str(round(int(price_round) * 30 / 100 + int(price_round)))
numer_4 = str(round(int(price_round) * 40 / 100 + int(price_round)))
```

Comment: ну так разделите на `10**8` и получите что вам надо

Comment: спасибо, все получилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто поделите свою цену на 100000000 или 10 ** 8 и все.